# A data structure for strings allowing efficient extraction of blocks?

Tags: arrays, string, data-structures

I am searching for dual use arrays (if there are any !)

for example

```
obj[1] = "Tea";
obj[2] = "Coffee";
obj[3] = "Cola";
```

The array should be accessible in such a way that no matter what the length of each string in the array is, the result should be pirnted out as

```
obj(5)(1) = "TeaCo" 
obj(5)(2) = "ffeeC" 
obj(5)(2) = "ola"
```

I know that we could write a code that loops through array and print out results as above, but is there a data structure that can directly do that ?

Comment: Do you need to update the array? That is, after it's constructed, will you ever write, for example, `obj[1] = "Foobar"`? In your example, `obj(5)(2)` has two different values. Is that a typo? Do you want `obj(3)(1)` to give you `"Tea"`, and `obj(3)(2)` to give you `"Cof"`? Your problem is insufficiently specified.

Comment: Obj(5)(2) only has 3 characters left in it so will end up with "ola", but you understood my rest of the question.

Comment: In your example, you have `obj(5)(2) = "ffeeC"`, followed by `obj(5)(2) = "ola"`. Should that last one be `obj(5)(3)`?

Comment: Yes, it is obj(5)(3).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your queries have the form

> If the input were split into blocks of size k, what would the rth block be?

Let's call a query of this sort a block-query(k, r).

You can support these queries in time O(k + log n), where n is the number of distinct strings, by using an augmented balanced binary tree. Annotate each node in the tree with the total number of characters in its left and right subtrees and also the number of strings in its left and right subtrees (in other words, make a variation of an order statistic tree). Additionally, thread a doubly-linked list through the nodes so that it's possible to navigate from any node to its successor in time O(1).

To insert or update a value at index i, search for the node corresponding to position i and either insert a new value right before it or update its contents.

To perform a block-query(k, r), search for the character at index kr by using the augmentation. This will take time O(log n). Then, until k characters have been read, keep reading characters from the current node, traversing to the next node by following the linked list if necessary. This will take time O(k) total, and probably a lot less if the average number of characters in a node is low.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You understood my question, but could it be possible without using statistic trees ?

Comment: @Epigene I'm not sure. You'll run into some challenges trying to insert and update strings at logical positions in the array without having to shuffle over a bunch of characters.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a data structure that can directly do that?"

Yes. It's a character array, also known as a string.

If your string is `"TeaCoffeeCola"`, then (in Java), `string.substring(0,5)` is `"TeaCo"`. `string.substring(5,5)` is `"ffeeC"`. And so on.

Regardless of the language you are using, you can easily write a function for yourself which extracts a range of characters from a string. That is all you need.

Comment: How would you use this structure to implement operations like "set the kth string to be some new string" or "insert a new string at logical position 4?"

Comment: @templatetypedef, I didn't know that was a requirement. In the question, you only talk about printing out slices. If you use a simple array, you will have to copy the suffix of the array up or down if you want to insert or remove characters. Whether that will have acceptable performance or not depends on how big the array will be.

Comment: @templatetypedef is looking at the right direction. I am looking for a way to get merged data present in different strings, not in one.